# Forcing non-SSL in htaccess only partly works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have tried this in my htaccess file in order to force users accessing my page over SSL to be redirected to the non-SSL version:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

This works when users are accessing the SSL version of **www.mydomain.com**, but not the SSL version of **mydomain.com**.

I think this is partly due to me having activated forwarding of users from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com on my web-hosting provider control panel.

Does anyone know how to get both to work?

Comment: What's the exact problem while using `http://domain.com`?

Comment: No problem there. The problem occurs when users try to access the SSL variant of http://domain.com. Some browsers give an error due to too many redirects, and some just says that the page cannot be displayed.

Comment: Don't use mod_rewrite and a redirection on the your providers control panel. You'll probably get a redirect loop as they might be fighting each other. Use one or the other. I wouldn't use the control panel option to do any type of forwarding.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea :) How would the htaccess file look if I want to implement both? That is, forwarding non-www to www, as well as the SSL version of both non-www and www to non-SSL www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would the htaccess file look if I want to implement both? That is, forwarding non-www to www, as well as the SSL version of both non-www and www to non-SSL www?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works for non-cached browsers, but not browsers which have visited my site previously. Some give the message "Too many redirects", and some say "Unable to connect" and some say "The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy" or "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: Update: Does not work for non-www, but does work for SSL non-www and others.

Comment: See the thing is that `301` redirects are cached aggressively by browsers. Hence, it's usually recommended to use only `[R]` during testing and switch to `301` when things settle down. I suggest you to use a completely different browser to avoid this issue. The rule for non-www to www works the same way for http and https. So, http one should start working as soon as the browser discards its cache.